# Наследование визуальных компонентов

Tags: ооп, c++builder, c++

Гугл ничего не дал. Компоненты создавать стандартным способом не входит в идею. Использую C++ builder. В целях повышения знаний хотелось бы создать класс, который к примеру наследует все от `TButton`.

```
class bob: public TButton
{
    public:
};
```

Основная проблема это конструктор. Вообще не получается его написать, выдается ошибка типа "не может найти конструктор чтобы инициализировать базовый класс" И если его переписывать, то как не напортачить так чтобы кнопка не создавалась.

```
bob ba= new bob(Form1);
```

Эт вторая проблемка. Есть вероятность, что она исчезнет когда решится первая.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А.Я.Архангельский, "Программирование С++ Builder 6", с.519, М., 2002. Я, руководствуясь этим, создавал объекты, наследуя от TChart, TEdit, TPanel, TSeries. Все получилось, пользуюсь по сей день.